# Locking all input devices on a Mac

Tags: macos, browser, osx-tiger, kiosk

We're trying to use an old MacBook running tiger to power a status screen here in the office. Basically, it's just a full-screen Firefox running a web page.

Problem is that the MacBook is on the internal network and could have access to sensitive files. What i'm looking for is some kind of utility that locks all keyboard and mouse access and enables it again when entering a   password or something, basically the same that screensaver does (except it doesn't show webpages :).

Answer (score 2):

What your wanting is a transparent screensaver, ie. still locks and demands a password if you touch the mouse or keyboard but shows the contents of the screen rather than some natty effect.

Here's one i found with a quick google. I've only done this on PC's before, but the principle should be the same on a mac.

http://www.monkeybreadsoftware.de/Freeware/Transparent.shtml

Comment: Note that in my experience writing screensavers, a screensaver that is *just* transparent will get an opaque black background behind it. That screen saver might be doing something special to be transparent despite locking.